# Copy the formula in Excel as it is done by dragging the cell over to another

Tags: excel, vba, formula, cell

```
For i = 1 To staffelRange.Rows.Count
   .DataBodyRange.Cells(i, countHeader).Formula = staffelRange.Cells(i).Formula
Next
```

> the code works as intended and copies the formulas from my range into the desired range in my table. first to the formula, the formula always refers to the column header and the cell left of it, if i copy the code now with my function from column 1 to for example column 4, the formula still refers to column 1 instead of column 4. but if i copy it by dragging the formula over to the other cell, the formula adapts. How can I achieve such an adjustment in my code? 
>   Formula:
>   =$G39*(1+SVERWEIS(Stückpreise_neu_19[[#Kopfzeilen];[Staffel1]];Rabattstaffel_new_24;2;FALSCH))

Comment: Perhaps [Range.Filldown method?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.filldown).

Comment: i tried it, i get an error that Filldown does not work with the .range in a table

Comment: To clarify, for example your formula might reference `A1` and if you copy it to row 4 it should then reference `A4`, is that right?

Comment: you might really add some screenshots and the formula

Comment: depending on exactly what you want to do, which is not clear to me from your question, you probably need to make appropriate changes in your formula.

Comment: @SamuelEverson yes thats right

Comment: i have added the formula

Comment: Show us the three formulas: The formula in column 1, the formula in column 4 and the desired formula in column 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the formula is always the same except for the cell reference, you can just write the formula to sheet as a string value with a variable for the correct row number.

Something like...

```
For i = 1 To staffelRange.Rows.Count
   .DataBodyRange.Cells(i, countHeader).Formula = "=$G" & i & "*1+SVERWEIS(Stückpreise_neu_19[[#Kopfzeilen];Staffel1]];Rabattstaffel_new_24;2;FALSCH))"
Next
```

This is assuming your variable `i` represents the correct row number for the formula (which to my understanding is correct).